# EditText with permanent indent at start

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

My EditText has a background that makes it round and with a stroke of 3dp, I am trying to have a permanent indent implemented so that the text doesn't start in the stroke of the background. All ive come across is android: paddingStart/paddingEnd and I can not seem to get it to work. Is there any other way of achieving this programmatically or no? I would want it about 1dp past the stroke or maybe 3dp but I can't find a way to achieve this.

xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/w_SearchBarFullScreen"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="355dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/web_search_bar"
      android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="    "
      android:elevation="5dp"
      android:focusable="true"/>
```

background xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#e0e0e0" />
<corners
    android:radius="15dp"/>

<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: your question is about edit text while you have posted code for textview ?

Comment: i realized that afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding in the background was stopping me from doing this so in `android:paddingLeft = 10dp` is the correct not in the layoutXML file rather the background

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding from background.xml

use `paddingLeft="10dp"`

in Edittext

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

no need to set fixed height and width for edittext here.

**.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.silambarasan.test.MainActivity"
  >

  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/w_SearchBarFullScreen"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/web_search_bar"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**web_search_bar.xml (Drawable)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#fff" />
  <stroke
     android:width="3dp"
     android:color="#e0e0e0" />
  <corners
     android:radius="15dp"/>
  <padding
     android:left="15dp"
     android:top="15dp"
     android:right="15dp"
     android:bottom="15dp" />
</shape>
```

**Result**:

[image: edittext]